# Why do buttons go off screen on Flow Layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout, flowlayout

I'm learning flow layout from Head First Java and I'm trying to have buttons wrap around as it says a `Flow Layout` should (left to right, top to bottom).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Flow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flow gui = new Flow();
        gui.go();
    }
    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton buttonOne = new JButton("hello");
        JButton buttonTwo = new JButton("this is");
        JButton buttowThree = new JButton("woody");

        panel.add(buttonOne);
        panel.add(buttonTwo);
        panel.add(buttonThree);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However, when setting the panel on the `EAST` region of the frame, the buttons go off the screen and don't wrap around. If I set the panel on the `NORTH` or `SOUTH` region, I only see two buttons. If I set the panel on the `CENTER` region, they DO wrap and can see all of them clearly. Why is this?

Comment: Hi Vader you are right that the answer I posted did not answer your question. I have appropriately deleted the answer. For what it's worth, my suggestion to you is to not get bogged down in FlowLayout's flaws (like I said, it always had limited usability) and instead use your time to learn some of the other LayoutManagers, like BoxLayout and BorderLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding a component to a `BorderLayout` frame, the `East` and `West` regions will let the component get its preferred width. Since the panel contains three buttons and places them side by side, the preferred width of the panel is that of the three buttons side by side. Therefore, it is going "off-the-screen" since that is the preferred width. If you were to a button on to the frame on the `EAST` region instead and fill it up with enough text, the same would happen.
 The `CENTER` region gets whatever is left that the other regions haven't taken up already. Since that is the policy of the `CENTER` region, the panel does **NOT** get its preferred width or height, therefore forcing the components of the panel to wrap.

As far as the `NORTH` and `SOUTH` regions go, the panel will get its preferred height which is the height of the tallest component (in the example all buttons are the same height). Therefore it sees no reason to wrap. The panel however, **DOESN'T** get its preferred width. Therefore the buttons are "cut off" since the max width the panel can have is that of the frame. You will notice as the frame resizes, the buttons appear on the screen as space is made available on the panel.